# Creating zip using express and archiver

Tags: node.js, express, archive, node-archiver

I used the node-archiver to zip files as follows. But I get corrupted zip file.

```
app.get('/download', async (req, res) => {

    const arch = archiver('zip');
    arch.append('abc', { name: 'abc.txt'});
    arch.append('cdf', { name: 'cdf.txt'});

    res.attachment('test.zip').type('zip');
    arch.pipe(res);
    arch.finalize();
});
```

I modified the code to save to the file system directly. With this code, I get a working zip file created on filesystem.

```
app.get('/download', async (req, res) => {


    const arch = archiver('zip');
    arch.append('abc', { name: 'abc.txt'});
    arch.append('cdf', { name: 'cdf.txt'});

    const output = fs.createWriteStream('./test.zip');
    arch.pipe(output);
    arch.finalize();
});
```

Why is zip file getting corrupted while sent via express `res` object? What would be the fix?

**Edit:**
If I use output format as `tar` instead of zip the it works without any problem.

```
const arch = archiver('tar');
```

Comment: For anyone seeing this in 2024, whatever bug the OP was facing has since been resolved. The approach here works for me with zip files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to close the response stream too:

```
app.get('/download', async (req, res) => {

    const arch = archiver('zip');
    arch.append('abc', { name: 'abc.txt'});
    arch.append('cdf', { name: 'cdf.txt'});

    res.attachment('test.zip').type('zip');
    arch.on('end', () => res.end()); // end response when archive stream ends
    arch.pipe(res);
    arch.finalize();
});
```

Comment: Just tried it. It didn't work. If archiver format is tar it works without closing the stream with `res.end()`